# Prove that $\forall\alpha\geq\omega$, $|L_\alpha|=|\alpha|$ without AC

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice, ordinals

Without using Axiom of Choice, prove that
$$\forall\alpha\geq\omega,~~|L_\alpha|=|\alpha|,$$

in which $\alpha$ is an ordinals, $\omega$ is the set of natural numbers, $L_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-th constructiable set, $|x|$ is the cardinals of $x$.

I am learning a set theory, and I have read a proof by using AC. The AC is used only when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinals during the transfinite inductive method for $\alpha$ . I wonder if there is a proof without AC. 　THANKS!

Comment: Why do you think there is an appeal to the axiom of choice, by the way?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Actually it is a lemma in the textbook with AC. But my teacher told us that it is also true without AC. So I am curious about the proof.

Comment: Sounds a bit odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can notice that for a limit ordinal $\delta$, $L_\delta\models V=L$ and in particular $L_\delta$ has a definable well-ordering of type $\delta$.

So the use of the axiom of choice can be removed and instead you can use the definable well-orderings for everything instead.

Then the proof is quite similar. First note that $L_\omega$ is countable; then proceed by induction. $L_{\alpha+1}$ has a bijection with $(L_\alpha)^{<\omega}\times\omega$ (by encoding formulas and parameters) and using the induction hypothesis $|\alpha|=|L_\alpha|=|L_{\alpha+1}|=|\alpha+1|$. When arriving to limit ordinals, use the fact that there is a definable well-ordering to conclude that $L_\delta$ is the union of uniformly well-ordered sets and conclude $|L_\delta|=|\delta|\cdot\sup\{|L_\alpha|\mid\alpha<\delta\}=|\delta|\cdot|\delta|=|\delta|$.

(All the cardinal arithmetic is true because it holds for ordinals without using choice.)

Note, by the way, that Gödel proved that the axiom of choice is at all consistent with the rest of the axioms of set theory by proving that it holds in $L$. So all the arguments about the construction of $L$ shouldn't, morally, appeal to the axiom of choice. And they don't.

Comment: +1. I can't resist also adding the following very silly proof: since $L\models ZFC$, $L$ satisfies (via the proof using choice that the OP mentioned) "$\vert L_\alpha\vert=\vert\alpha\vert$" for every ordinal $\alpha\ge\omega$. That is, for each ordinal $\alpha\ge\omega$, there is an $f_\alpha\in L$ such that $L$ satisfies "$f_\alpha$ is a bijection between $L_\alpha$ and $\alpha$." Since $L$ is absolute, for each $\alpha\ge\omega$ $V$ also satisfies "$f_\alpha$ is a bijection between $L_\alpha$ and $\alpha$,"  so we're done because $V$ and $L$ have the same ordinals.

Comment: Noah, yeah, these arguments are fun but they feel like cheating. Which is probably why all that time I ago, I opted for repeating the same proof as before.